# java.net.URL bug in constructing URLs?

Tags: java, url, construction

The construct `new URL(new URL(new URL("http://localhost:4567"), "abc"), "def")` produces (imho incorrectly) this url: `http://localhost:4567/def`

While the construct `new URL(new URL(new URL("http://localhost:4567"), "abc/"), "def")` produces the correct (wanted by me) url: `http://localhost:4567/abc/def`

The difference is a trailing slash in `abc` constructor argument.

Is this intended behavior or this is a bug that should be fixed in URL class?
After all the idea is not to worry about slashes when you use some helper class for URL construction.

Comment: Claiming that a well tested class in the SDK has a bug is usually quite a bold statement.

Comment: I don't claim anything. Just asking for explanation of that behavior.

Comment: Well, you might want to go through the `URL` class sources to see if there's anything helpful. Most likely not a bug, even if it doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: @Kayaman Before going to the source code, it's always better to read the javadoc first, since that describes the intended behavior. The result seen here is exactly the behavior described in the javadoc.

Comment: @Andreas Going to the source shows you the javadoc as well, in addition to any possible hidden comments in the code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting javadoc of [`new URL(URL context, String spec)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Otherwise, the path is treated as a relative path and is appended to the context path, as described in RFC2396.

See section 5 "Relative URI References" of the [RFC2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) spec, specifically section 5.2 "Resolving Relative References to Absolute Form", item 6a:

> All but the last segment of the base URI's path component is copied to the buffer.  In other words, any characters after the last (right-most) slash character, if any, are excluded.

*Explanation*

On a web page, the "Base URI" is the page address, e.g. `http://example.com/path/to/page.html`. A relative link, e.g. `<a href="page2.html">`, must be interpreted as a *sibling* to the base URI, so `page.html` is removed, and `page2.html` is added, resulting in `http://example.com/path/to/page2.html`, as intended.

The Java `URL` class implements this logic, and that is why you get what you see, and it is entirely the way it is supposed to work.

**It is by design, i.e. not a bug.**